# Why LaTex is changing I to i?

Tags: latex

I've my resume in latex, and everything looks good, except this.

Original in latex:

```
\cventry
  {Senior Software Engineer}
```

Definition of cventry:

```
% Define an entry of cv information
% Usage: \cventry{<position>}{<title>}{<location>}{<date>}{<description>}
\newcommand*{\cventry}[5]{%
  \vspace{-2.0mm}
  \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
  \setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt}
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} L{\textwidth - 4.5cm} R{4.5cm}}
    \ifempty{#2#3}
      {\entrypositionstyle{#1} & \entrydatestyle{#4} \\}
      {\entrytitlestyle{#2} & \entrylocationstyle{#3} \\
      \entrypositionstyle{#1} & \entrydatestyle{#4} \\}
    \multicolumn{2}{L{\textwidth}}{\descriptionstyle{#5}}
  \end{tabular*}%
}
```

Text rendered:

```
SENiOR SOFTWARE ENGiNEER
```

Why does the title get capitalized except for the letter i?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AwesomeCV uses the Source Sans Pro font for position titles and I guess the issue is there.

**Error replication**:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
%\usepackage[default]{sourcesanspro}

\begin{document}
    \textsc{Software Architect}
\end{document}
```

If you copy the text with the standard font you get "Software Architect".

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[default]{sourcesanspro}

\begin{document}
    \textsc{Software Architect}
\end{document}
```

However, with Source Sans Pro you get "SOFTWARE ARCHiTECT". Note that the text rendered on screen looks fine, the issue arises if you copy the text.

To get rid of this you need either to change the font or put

```
% copied from awesome-cv.cls
% just below the name
\renewcommand*{\headerpositionstyle}[1]{{\fontsize{7.6pt}{1em}\bodyfont\color{awesome} \uppercase{#1}}}
% normal entries
\renewcommand*{\entrypositionstyle}[1]{{\fontsize{8pt}{1em}\bodyfont\color{graytext} \uppercase{#1}}}
% didn't see this one
\renewcommand*{\subentrypositionstyle}[1]{{\fontsize{7pt}{1em}\bodyfont\color{graytext} \uppercase{#1}}}
```

in your preamble. This overwrites the position style definition from small caps to caps, leaving you with "SOFTWARE ARCHITECT". If you like a different style, just adjust these three lines.